# LINUX удаление файлов кроме одного

Tags: linux

Есть команда, удаляет все .txt файлы. Как сделать так, чтобы удаляла так же .txt файлы, только кроме robots.txt?

`find /home/u20806/public_html -maxdepth 1 -mmin +5 -type f -name "*.txt" -delete`

Answer (score 4):

Вот так:

```
find /home/u20806/public_html \
     -maxdepth 1 \
     -mmin +5 \
     -type f \
     -name "*.txt" \
     ! -name "robots.txt" \
     -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

`find /home/u20806/public_html -name "robots.txt" -o -maxdepth 1 -mmin +5 -type f -name "*.txt" -delete`

Answer (score 0):

На выбор

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -iwholename '*Video'
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -iname file.txt
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -samefile /home/nez/file.txt 
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' -not -name File.txt
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex '.*\.txt' -not -name File.txt
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -regex '.*\.txt'
```